# How to properly check checkboxes depends on the permissions of a role?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have implemented Laratrust role system in my Laravel application. Now, I'm rendering all available roles to a superadministrator in order to add new permissions or delete them from a specific role.

Here's my `AclController`:

```
public function index()
{
    $roles = Role::all();
    $permissions = Permission::all();
    $temp = array();

    foreach($permissions as $key => $value) {
        array_push($temp, $value['name']);
    }

    return view('pages.acl.index')->with([ 'roles' => $roles, 'permissions' => $permissions, 'temp' => $temp ]);
}
```

and the `.blade` template where I display the permissions and checkbox:

```
<div class="tabs-vertical-env">
    <ul class="nav tabs-vertical" style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        @foreach ($roles as $role)
            <li class="">
                <a href="#{{ $role['name'] }}" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">{{ $role['display_name'] }}</a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        @foreach ($roles as $role)
            <div class="tab-pane" id="{{ $role['name'] }}">
                @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ $permission['name'] }}" id="{{ $permission['name'] }}" {{ in_array($role->permissions, $temp) ? 'checked' : '' }} />
                        <label for="{{ $permission['name'] }}">
                            {{ $permission['display_name'] }}
                        </label>
                    </div>   
                @endforeach                               
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. What's the workaround?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work __how__? Your pc explodes?

Comment: @u_mulder checkboxes are not checked

Comment: @u_mulder but why other functions like `isset(), empty()` work properly?

Comment: @u_mulder it is supported in blade if you use it like he does

Comment: @КамиловТимур you should try and dump you variables $roles and $permissions and see how they look. Do they really look like you expected?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 I guess my way is not the best and correct and I want to ask if there's an easier and more clear and correct way to achieve the purpose?

Comment: Can you add output of "dump($roles[0]);" to question? Then I'll most likely be able to point out what's wrong with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
<div class="tabs-vertical-env">
    <ul class="nav tabs-vertical" style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        @foreach ($roles as $role)
            <li class="">
                <a href="#{{ $role['name'] }}" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">{{ $role['display_name'] }}</a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        @foreach ($roles as $role)
            <div class="tab-pane" id="{{ $role['name'] }}">
                @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                        <input 
                                type="checkbox" 
                                name="roles[{{ $role['id'] }}][permissions][{{ $permission['id'] }}]" 
                                id="{{ $role['name'] }}_{{ $permission['name'] }}" 
                                value="{{ $permission['id'] }}" 
                                {{ $role->hasPermission($permission['name']) ? 'checked' : '' }} 
                        />
                        <label for="{{ $role['name'] }}_{{ $permission['name'] }}">
                            {{ $permission['display_name'] }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response)